# How to add scraped data with puppetteer into html

Tags: html, node.js, puppeteer

ADVISORY : I'm trying my hands at this for the first time.

I created an html page that displays bus timings. To get the bus timings I had to scrape the local bus service website with puppeteer. I do scrape the time for the next bus correctly, but I can't seem to add it to my html page.

I've tried adding the script tags with src pointing to my js file. I tried adding them to the head, in the div that should display the time and right before the closing body tag, but I couldn't display the time. I event tried to add the js in a script tag to the html and that didn't work.

```
//Here's code for scraping in busTimeScraper.js :
  let scrape = async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('bustimes.com');    //Dummy website for this eg
  await page.setViewport({width: 1500, height: 1500})
  await page.waitFor(5000);

  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
     let time = document.querySelector('#RouteTimetable').innerText;
     return {
        time
     }
 });

 browser.close();
 return result;

 };

 scrape().then((value) => {
    var timing = value.time;
    document.querySelector('#Time').innerText=timing;
 });

//The html is :
 <div id="Time">
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="busTimeScraper.js">
          </script>-->
 </div>
```

I can see the time being scraped when I run the js file and do a console.log on the timing variable. I expected the div to be populated with the same time value, but it just stays blank

Comment: I can't see it open your html file

Comment: @ewwink if the two files are in the same directory, would it not work?

Comment: Is it a electron app or a simple html file?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher It's a simple HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot add your server-side JS in your client-side html using a script tag and expect it to work, no matter where you add (in head, inside element or before closing body);

Simplest solution would be to expose the result (timing variable) VIA NodeJsAPI and consume the API VIA your client-side JS to get the value and do rest of the client-side things.

Comment: Sorry, @Zunayed, but what does consume VIA client-side JS mean? (I'm just starting out, so the technical jargon confuses me)

Comment: Sorry for reaching you lately. By consume I meant sending an HTTP/AJAX request just like you do to get data from any REST API